# Powershell script on Exchange server returns 800+ records out of 62000. Why?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've used script below to extract all *.pdf attachments from mailbox (needed to perform only once). It's a mailbox where reports was sent, so it contains only messages with specific name and attachment.
And it returns only 800+ records out of 60+ thousands. Any advice how to modify it?
I've tried to change ItemView from 1000 to 63000, nothing changed.

```
# Name of the mailbox to pull attachments from
$MailboxName = 'maibox@domain.com'
 
# Location to move attachments
$downloadDirectory = 'E:\ToExport'
 
# Path to the Web Services dll
$dllpath = "E:\Exchange\V15\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[VOID][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
 
# Create the new web services object
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2019)
 
# Create the LDAP security string in order to log into the mailbox
$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind
 
# Auto discover the URL used to pull the attachments
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())
 
# Get the folder id of the Inbox
$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
 
# Find mail in the Inbox with attachments
$Sfha = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::HasAttachments, $true)
$sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And);
$sfCollection.add($Sfha)
 
# Grab all the mail that meets the prerequisites
$view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(63000)
$frFolderResult = $InboxFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)
 
# Loop through the emails
foreach ($miMailItems in $frFolderResult.Items){
 
    # Load the message
    $miMailItems.Load()
 
    # Loop through the attachments
    foreach($attach in $miMailItems.Attachments){
 
        # Load the attachment
        $attach.Load()
 
        # Save the attachment to the predefined location
        $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream(($downloadDirectory + “\” + $attach.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)       
                $fiFile.Write($attach.Content, 0, $attach.Content.Length)
        $fiFile.Close()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView()`**

Will only accept a maximum of 1000, within the response from `$InboxFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)` you will be given a boolean property of "MoreAvailable", you would increase the `offset` by `1000` and iterate through until `MoreAvailable` is `False`.

Please see your script edited below to incorporate this (Lines 32,33, 38-43 includes comments and changes):

```
# Name of the mailbox to pull attachments from
$MailboxName = 'maibox@domain.com'
 
# Location to move attachments
$downloadDirectory = 'E:\ToExport'
 
# Path to the Web Services dll
$dllpath = "E:\Exchange\V15\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[VOID][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
 
# Create the new web services object
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2019)
 
# Create the LDAP security string in order to log into the mailbox
$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind
 
# Auto discover the URL used to pull the attachments
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())
 
# Get the folder id of the Inbox
$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
 
# Find mail in the Inbox with attachments
$Sfha = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::HasAttachments, $true)
$sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And);
$sfCollection.add($Sfha)
 
# Grab all the mail that meets the prerequisites
$frFolderResults = @() # Create array
$view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000)
$frFolderResult = $InboxFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)
$frFolderResults += $frFolderResult    


### Start While loop to include offset +1000 until $frFolderResult.MoreAvailable is false
While ($frFolderResult.MoreAvailable){
    $view.offset += 1000
    $frFolderResult = $InboxFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)
    $frFolderResults += $frFolderResult
}    

 
# Loop through the emails
foreach ($miMailItems in $frFolderResults.Items){
 
    # Load the message
    $miMailItems.Load()
 
    # Loop through the attachments
    foreach($attach in $miMailItems.Attachments){
 
        # Load the attachment
        $attach.Load()
 
        # Save the attachment to the predefined location
        $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream(($downloadDirectory + “\” + $attach.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)       
                $fiFile.Write($attach.Content, 0, $attach.Content.Length)
        $fiFile.Close()
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i needed.

Comment: @AlexanderK you're welcome, as this has resolved your issue, could you please mark the answer as correct by using clicking the green checkmark on the left of the answer.